# Does Colonel Adye die?

Tags: the-invisible-man

I have *The Invisible Man* as a book in twelfth grade. Our teacher says Colonel Adye is alive. But I think he is dead as it is stated he does't move.

So is he dead or alive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## He's probably dead, but there's a possibility that he's alive.

I think that the text makes this pretty clear:

> Adye leapt backwards, swung around, clutched at this little object, missed it, threw up his hands and fell forward on his face, leaving a little puff of blue in the air. Kemp did not hear the sound of the shot. Adye writhed, raised himself on one arm, fell forward, and lay still.
> <sub>*The Invisible Man*, chapter 27: "The Siege of Kemp's House"</sub>

> Everything was safe and quiet. He returned to the belvedere. Adye lay motionless over the edge of the gravel just as he had fallen. Coming along the road by the villas were the housemaid and two policemen.
> <sub>*The Invisible Man*, chapter 27: "The Siege of Kemp's House"</sub>

So we see that he's shot and that he isn't moving. Now we see that the characters in the story think he's dead:

> "The Invisible Man!" said Kemp. "He has a revolver, with two shots left. **He's killed Adye**. Shot him anyhow. Didn't you see him on the lawn? He's lying there."
> "Who?" said one of the policemen.
> "Adye," said Kemp.
> <sub>*The Invisible Man*, chapter 27: "The Siege of Kemp's House"</sub>

And that's the last we ever hear about Adye. So while it's implied that he died, there's a possibility that he's alive that's mentioned in the book itself. So we can't be really sure.

Comment: Hmm. To my mind "*motionless*" would tend to strongly imply "dead".

Comment: @Valorum - sure, but it's left as a possibility in the book that he's alive - *"Shot him anyhow."* I agree that it sounds he's dead - and that's what I wrote in the answer ;) But it does leave open the possibility, so...

Comment: Ok. So if I get a question in the exams, do I write it is ambiguous? He could be either dead or alive.

Comment: @ShantanuHebbar - that's probably what I'd write. But we're not here to do your exams for you, so write what you want ;)

Answer (score -2):

although later on in the novel, Adye is mentioned as one the people who got interviewed with marvel.

Comment: "later on in the novel" - where exactly? Do you have a relevant quote from the novel? This would be a much better answer if backed up with an explicit quote.